# jQuery add event and instantly execute it

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

Often there is situation when I need to add some event with some customizations and then apply those customizations on page ready.

Usually I was doing it like:

```
        $(window).resize(function(){
            //some code
        }).resize(); //trigger it when event defined
```

Problem with this solution is that if I have many resize events, then if I trigger it like this - it will re-execute all previously defined events too.

So another solution could be:

```
    var myCallback = function(){ /*some code*/ };
    $(window).resize(function(){
        myCallback();
    });
    myCallback();
```

And it does it correctly but I find it not so good looking code and also there is no `this` inside function changed to event target DOM element that is very useful quite often.

Great would be something like

```
$(window).addEventAndFireOnce("resize", function(){});
```

such function is not so hard to implement, but I'm wondering if there is something like this there already in js or jQuery.

Comment: you can use trigger() in jquery

Comment: You could always [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/) jQuery to write your function.

Comment: @theinvisible: That would have the same problem the OP describes after his first code block.

Comment: in the window resize case I allways use some timeout - to delay it for few miliseconds (as appropriate)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I'm alone in this, but if I need to do that (and it's not uncommon) I bind a custom event name (possibly with a scope) at the same time as I bind the real event ("click" or "change" or whatever):

```
var myCallback = function(ev) { ... };

$(window).on("resize my-resize", myCallback).trigger("my-resize");
```

That's particularly useful when you're handling something like a "click" event on a checkbox. Triggering the "click" will actually update the checkbox "checked" state, which is not generally what you'd want to do. There's the jQuery `.triggerHandler()` method, but for whatever reason that only works on the first element in the jQuery object, so you can't trigger the handlers for all the checkboxes in a form with one call.

Comment: Or using a namespace: `$(window).on("resize.foo", function() { }).trigger("resize.foo");`

Comment: Updating state on init is exacly what I need. Its good solution. I'm thinking how creative you're getting in creating new event names all the time :) It would be good to have something like $(window).on("event", callback, true); where true mean fire callback on adding event.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes - again, I got into the habit of using custom events paired with real ones to avoid annoying issues with events on interactive elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like so:

```
var myCallback = function(){ /*some code*/ };
$(window).resize( myCallback );
myCallback();
```

Comment: @Pointy: It will in loose mode, as the default `this` is...the global object (which is the window object on browsers). But usually people don't care about `this` in handlers attached to `window` anyway.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, true for this particular example and more generally for `window` handlers I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for here is namespaced handlers

```js
var log = (function() {
  var $log = $('#log');
  return function(msg) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: msg
    }).appendTo($log)
  }
})();

$(window).resize(function() {
  log('handler 1');
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  log('handler 2');
});

$(window).on('resize.myspecial', function() {
  log('handler 3');
}).trigger('resize.myspecial');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: The only problem I see here is requirement of 'inventing' new namespaces all the time I'm adding new event of same type - that is not very comfortable when you have a lot of resize events.

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak just add namespace for the specific one. Not sure i understood your comment

Comment: Let's say you've got 5 more resize events that you want to triger same way as resize.myspecial. You'd need to add another namespaces like resize.myspecial-2 resize.myspecial-3 etc. If you would not - you'd get big group of resize.myspecial events and basically go into same situation as with raw event.

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak You can use same namespace for as many events you wish, again, i don't really see issue here. Now regarding Pointy's answer, using custom event instead could be more appropriate in some situations, not sure about yours